# I have updated my code-- I want to pass an object in "for loop" with employee_id and his specific donation amount, How can I do this?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am working on a donation app. In this app, There was a feature that sends an equal amount of donation money to every employee of the organization now they want to change this feature by sending a customized amount of donation to all or some of the employees.
I have worked on it: Now I am using a for loop which iterates over the list of employees id and gives the amount to each id. But What I want is to pass an object in a `for loop`, where the object has an `id` from `list of ids` and the `amount` received from `payload`. I want to keep that `id` with his specific `amount` locked in an object
Here is my code now:

```
class BusinessDonationController(BaseController):
    def create(self, request, response, business):
        employees =Employment.objects.filter(business=business, active=True)
        ids = employees.values_list('id', flat=True)
        donation_amount = []
        for id in ids:
            try:
                amount = int(request.payload.get("amount"))
                donation_amount.append({
                    "id" : id,
                    "amount" : amount
                })
            except ValueError:
                return response.bad_request("Invalid donation amounts, %s, should be in whole dollars" % amount)
        return donation_amount
```

Comment: Where do you get the different amounts from? It looks like there is a JSON body coming in in the request with an amount per employee, but you cast that whole dictionary to a single dictionary, which I don't understand.

Comment: By the way, you can simplify `if error != '' and error is not None:` to `if error:`, and `response.set(**{'success': True}` can be written as `response.set(success=True}`

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please see the updated code? I need quick suggestion

Comment: You still take only one single amount from the request data, instead of an amount per employee. Can you show the request and the response data that you expect to receive in this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked for me!!

```
class BusinessDonationController(BaseController):
    def create(self, request, response, business):
        business = Business.objects.get(id=business)
        employees =Employment.objects.filter(business=business, active=True)
        ids = employees.values_list('id', flat=True)
        donation_amount = []
        try:
            employee_id = int(request.payload.get("employee_id"))
            amount = int(request.payload.get("amount"))
            donation_amount.append({
                "employee_id" : employee_id,
                "amount" : amount
            })
        except ValueError:
            return response.bad_request("Invalid donation amounts, %s, should be in whole dollars" % amount)

        for employee in employees:
            if employee.id == employee_id:
                credit_account = CreditAccount.objects.create(deposit=deposit, total_amount=amount, current_amount=amount, employment=employee)
        if error != '' and error is not None:
            return response.bad_request(error)

        response.set(**{'success': True})
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach I can think of is, you can customize the amount of donation of some/all employees and distribute the rest to others equally. For example:

> I want to donate **$10,000** to **10** employees. Originally, each of
> them would receive **$1000**. But I want Employee-A and Employee-B to
> receive
> **$1200** and **$1300** respectively. Now I am left with **$8500** and **8** employees. So, each **8** of them will receive **$1062.5**.

### Implementation: (AJAX + DRF)

You have to add some input fields in your front-end. This is to customize which employee should receive how much donation. You should keep track of the `employeeId` as you will need it later while sending the payload to your server.

Create a JSON list (from your form) like this and pass it to the API call.

```js
let payload = [
    {"employee_id": 1, "amount": 1300.0},
    {"employee_id": 2, "amount": 1200.0},
]
```

You can use any method to send the data. For example: in **AJAX** you would something like that:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/your/api/endpoint/",
    data: {
        // Send `donation_amount` too.
        // This will help to validate data in backend.
        donation_amount: 10000.0,

        customized_amounts: payload
    },
    traditional: true,

    beforeSend: function () {
        // show some loading animation.
    },

    success: function (data) {
        // show a success toast or redirect.
    },

    error: function (error) {
        // show some error toast.
    },
});
```

In the backend create a serializer:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.utils.text import gettext_lazy as _

# TODO: from .models import Business


class DonationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    business = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(label=_('Business'), queryset=Business.objects.all(), required=True)
    donation_amount = serializers.FloatField(label=_('Donation Amount'), required=True, min_value=0.0)
    customized_amounts = serializers.JSONField(label=_('Customized Amounts'), default=list, required=False)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        donation_amount = attrs.get('donation_amount', 0.0)
        customized_amounts = attrs.get('customized_amounts', [])

        if donation_amount == 0.0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Donation cannot be empty!'))

        partial_sum = 0.0
        for data in customized_amounts:
            # Checking if employee_id is valid or not
            employee_id = data.get('employee_id')
            if not Employment.objects.filte(id=employee_id).exitst():
                raise serializers.ValidationError(_(f'Employee with id: ${employee_id} does not exists!'))

            # summing up amount to check if it exceeds total amount
            partial_sum += data.get('amount')

        if partial_sum > donation_amount:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Individual donation amount exceeds total amount!'))

        # add any other validation you want.

        return attrs

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass
```

and an API endpoint:

```py
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

# TODO: from .models import Employment
# TODO: from .tasks import run_employee_donation


class DonationCreateAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = DonationSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        business = serializer.validated_data.get('business')
        donation_amount = serializer.validated_data.get('donation_amount')
        customized_amounts = serializer.validated_data.get('customized_amounts')

        employee_qs = Employment.objects.filter(business=business, active=True)
        total_employees = employee_qs.count()

        donation_per_employee = donation_amount / (total_employees - len(customized_amounts))

        for employee in employee_qs:
            customized_amount = [data for data in customized_amounts if data['employee_id'] == employee.id]

            if len(customized_amount) > 0:
                # Customized donation for this employee found.
                run_employee_donation(employee_id=employee.id, amount=customized_amount[0].get('amount'))
            else:
                run_employee_donation(employee_id=employee.id, amount=donation_per_employee)

        return Response({'success': True}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Sayed Al Mahdi I am not using rest framework

Comment: @Djangodev are you using regular django and django-forms?

Comment: Yes I am using regular django

Comment: Hello! Can you see my code now?

Comment: Before answering I need some clarification. Do you just want to pass an object to the for loop? or do you want to know how to pass an object from the client to the backend and then process it in the for loop?

Comment: I want to know how to pass an object from the client to the backend and then process it in ```for loop```

Comment: Can you please show me your current approach of sending data from the client (ie: HTML/JavaScript) so that I can suggest a proper adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

create a model to store employee and donation. List all employees. user can click on an employee name to display a form to edit the amount.

Comment: I have updated the code, Can you please check now?

Comment: Can you please check and suggest something

Comment: I think you are making it complex , it is very simple , if I have understood the problem. just create a simple Django model with two fields , employee a foreign key and amount. then show a form to user to enter default amount for each employee , update that amount in your model for each employee.  Final step , list all employees and user can click on an employee name to change the amount.